# Test a function from reducer file with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I'm having problems to test a simple function with Jest.

```
export const removeId = (obj, omitId) => {
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((object, key) => {
    if (key !== omitId) {
      object[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return object;
  }, {});
};
```

When I import this function to my test file and run:

```
  expect(removeId(state, 0)).toEqual(expected);
```

the expect value is undefined.

But if I declare the function inside the test and run like:

```
const removeId = Object.keys(state).reduce((object, key) => {
        if (key !== '2') {
          object[key] = state[key];
        }
        return object;
      }, {});
expect(removeId).toEqual(expected);
```

Works fine.

Comment: I feel like your missing a `return` at the start of your `Object.keys(obj)` line.  Since your arrow function is using `{}` it shouldn't be performing an implicit return, afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was already provided by Taplar in the comment, but I have a feeling that your issue comes from a misunderstanding of what Object.keys is doing. If that's not correct and this was just a typo, feel free to ignore the rest of this post. First, this is the correct code that should work:

```
export const removeId = (obj, omitId) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((object, key) => {
    if (key !== omitId) {
      object[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return object;
  }, {});
};
```

But why does this work, and why didn't it work before? I have a feeling that you put `return object` and though that would be sufficient. The reason it's not enough is because the `reduce` function is actually taking a closure, which means it's a totally different function. To understand this, we can break the code apart like so:

```
export const removeId = (obj, omitId) => {
  const innerFunction = (object, key) => {
    if (key !== omitId) {
      object[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return object;
  };

  Object.keys(obj).reduce(innerFunction, {});
};
```

Now notice the line with the `reduce` function on it is basically just a chained statement. We're calling it, but we're not doing anything with the result.

To look at this another way:

```
Object.keys(obj) -> returns an array, the contents of which are the
keys of the object that you put into it

array.reduce() -> calls a function for every element of the array. It returns
an object built from that function
```

So in order to get the result of the `reduce` function to be sent back from your `removeId` function, you need to return it, which is what the top code does.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped and made me understand it!